# Mysql order distinc select

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a simple select and I want the results to be ordered alphabetically.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type
FROM cars
WHERE make = 'FORD'
ORDER BY type
```

I get this result:

```
FORD FOCUS
FORD FOCUS C-MAX
FORD FUSION
FORD S-MAX
FORD TRANSIT
FORD C-MAX
FORD FIESTA
FORD FOCUS
FORD FOCUS C-MAX
FORD FUSION
FORD GALAXY
FORD KA
FORD MONDEO
FORD S-MAX
FORD TRANSIT
FORD TRANSIT CONNECT
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: That's not what I get: [JSFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf24/4/0)

Comment: You didn't use the ORDER BY when you got this, that's the whole purpose of the keyword use.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, this JSFiddle is exactly the same as yours http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73b15/1

Comment: Show us your real table structure, using sql fiddle. gloomy penguin did a great job, creating a hypothetical one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, you got the structure right,  sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73b15/1 is similar to what I have.

My query was actually correct, as I wanted to create an sqlfiddle I noticed that the data from  the db was not correct, I had some spaces at the begining of "type" :(

Answer (score 0):

it seems `type` is a keyword, try

```
order by `type`
```